# Restyling Bootstrap Components with React/Typescript styled components

Tags: reactjs, components, styles, react-bootstrap, styled-components

I hava menu bar from bootstrap, but I would like to change some colors, e.g.button styles.

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

              <Header__Button>
                    Something
                </Header__Button>

const Header__Button = styled(Button)`
    color: '#003D58';
    background: 'transparent';
`;
```

This was my approach to do it, but it does not work. What is the correct and working way to handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
const styles = css `
   .custom-button {
    color: '#003D58';
    background: 'transparent';
}`;

<div css={styles}>
  <Button className='custom-button'>Hello</Button>
</div>
```

Comment: Where would the {styles} be applied in my example ?

Answer (score 0):

The `styled-components` package uses the same syntax that use would use in a CSS stylesheet rather than in a Javascript object.  So **you don't want to use quotes** around the values.  Removing them will fix it:

```
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Header__Button = styled(Button)`
    color: #003D58;
    background: transparent;
`;
```